# Java, Did I build this key detection class right?

Tags: java, input, key, listeners

Sorry for the abstract question title, I didn't know what to call it.... I thought I built this right, and I added the new listener to the object I want it to effect, but it doesn't do anything. Is it something wrong in this class? If no, then I know the bug is elsewhere...

```
public class key implements KeyListener{

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            m = true;
            break;
        }

    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent e) {
        switch(e.getKeyCode()){
        case KeyEvent.VK_SPACE:
            m = false;
            break;
        }

    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {

    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should add some `default` statements in your `switch`.

Answer (score 1):

Things I see you could / should change:

- **This may cause your problem:** Where is `m` defined? As ouf your code, it is undefined.
- Class names should start with an uppercase letter. `Key` instead of `key`
- Add `default` statements to your `switch`. As you use it at the moment, it is far enough to us a simple `if` there is not advantage to use `switch`.

Comment: The m is defined elsewhere in the code, I decided not to include it because that would be a hassle.... I am also planning on adding a ton of other stuff to the switch statement, its just that I wanted to make sure that it would work before I did anything else...